# Adding days to a getdate function

Tags: joomla, invoice

I would like to add more dates to my hikashop invoice. At default there is only creation date:

`<?php echo JText::_('DÁTUM VYHOTOVENIA').': '.hikashop_getDate($this->element->order_created,'%d %B %Y ');?>`

I would like to add two more dates (creation date + 5 days, and creation date + 20 days).
Can you please help me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$add_days = 5;
$date_fivedays = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->element->order_created) + (24*3600*$add_days));

$add_days = 20;
$date_twentydays = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->element->order_created) + (24*3600*$add_days));
```

Hope its helps..